# CountDownTimer context

Tags: android

How can I register a listener inside a `CountDownTimer`?

```
accelerometer = mSensorManager.registerListener(this,
mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

This works fine except when I put it inside a `CountDownTimer`.

```
public void startStopAcelerometer() {
 new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

  public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
   txtOut4.setText("Faltan: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000 + " segundos");
  }

  public void onFinish() {
   txtOut4.setText("Adelante!");
   mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
   mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

  accelerometer = mSensorManager.registerListener(this,
   mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

  button1.setText("Stop");
  }

 }.start();

}
```

When I put the code inside a `CountDownTimer`, the error is

```
The method registerListener(SensorEventListener, Sensor, int) in the type SensorManager is not applicable for the arguments (new CountDownTimer(){}, Sensor, int)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write `this` inside your `CountDownTimer` you will reference the `CountDownTimer` instead of your `SensorEventListener`.

If you declare your listener as below

```
private SensorEventListener listener = new SensorEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }
};
```

You can reference it like this inside your `CountDownTimer`

```
accelerometer = mSensorManager.registerListener(listener,
mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

Comment: Thanks Marcus. I've tried it, but I've had to cast to SensorEventListener the getApplicationContext().
Then, it gives an error of invalid cast:
android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.hardware.SensorEventListener